# Sum((Close 2 - Close 1)/Close 1) in a google spreadsheet

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

Suppose the two following columns :

```
Close 1   Close 2
$4.28       $4.90
$37.26      $33.87
$5.34       $5.16
$887.06     $734.70
$2.68       $2.55
$14.57      $13.51
$16.76      $10.82
$1.60       $1.18
$5.15       $4.09
```

This is part of my database. Suppose **Close 1** is the price close in January 1st and **Close 2** is the close price in January 2nd. Each line in the above table is a different stock. I want to sum up the % change for each of these stock without creating another column. The equation might look like Sum((Close 2 - Close 1)/Close 1). How can I apply that in a google spreadsheet?

I tried the following line :

```
=Sum((Database!$N$2:$N$51-Database!$L$2:$L$51)/Database!$L$2:$L$51)
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR((A2:A-B2:B)/A2:A))
```

[image]